# Load / Include Javascript Files in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to know how I can include individual JavaScript files on their respective pages in PHP.

I have separated my template into `header.php`, `sidebar.php`, `index.php` and `footer.php`, right now I have all the javascript in one file: `global.js` which I load in the footer section.

I have a chat in my application which I load also in my but because of that whenever you are on any other page apart from the chat page the script generates errors, because it cannot find the specified elements.

If I have a page like `contact.html`, I would like to know how I can load the JavaScript unique only to that page eg. `contact.js` without having to just dump it in the footer section and have it loaded whether or not you're on the contact page.

Comment: I have no idea why this post received a negative vote, since many of the comments made were not helpful in any way at all with the exception of Andy Holme's post.

Comment: I already answered my own question before you closed it, it is already clear enough as it is so i will not be making any changes, many thanks to Andy Holmes for his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so on the page itself i constructed an array and filled it with the path locations of the various javascript files i wanted to load.

```
$enqueue = array('contact.js', 'global.js');
```

Then in the footer section i looped through each element of the array and echoed it on the page right before the closing body tag.

```
foreach ($enqueue as $js) {
  echo "<script src='js/" . $js . "' type='text/javascript'></script>";
}
```

Loading many javascript files on your page within your header does actually slow down the time it takes for your page to load so it is much better to load such files right before the closing body tag of your page.

Answer (score 2):

Just echo your files on the pages it's needed like this:

```
echo '<script src="path/to/js/file.js"></script>';
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to echo the script right before the closing body tag?

Comment: Yes but i read somewhere that it actually makes your page load slower when you do that.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Put the PHP code i've put here before the closing body tag, simple. It is usually better to load JS scripts after content as it can block content load

Comment: Thank you all but i will not be loading my javascript files in my head section unless i absolutely need to, it does slow down the load time of the page especially since i have alot of javascript files. I figured out exactly how to do what i asked, see my answer. :)

Comment: Should have said in your question that you needed to use multiple files, you said individual files on the first line :P

Comment: The reason i did not accept your answer is that the closing body tag is in the footer.php not on the index.php.  Though you just gave me an idea though thanks. :) @Andy Holmes

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted :)